# Android Up button definition not clear enough for detailed view activities with multiple entry points

Tags: android, navigation

I have an `Activity` A which is the landing-home screen, an `Activity` B which is a list of items and an `Activity` C which shows the detailed view of one of the items of the list.

`Activity` C can be started from both `Activity` A and `Activity` B. (Some elements of the list are featured in the home screen)

My question is: should the up button of `Activity` C always take the user to `Activity` B (the list, even if the user started `Activity` C from `Activity` A) or should it behave as a back button and send the user to the `Activity` that started `Activity` C?

From the design guide I read:

> Navigating to screens with multiple entry points:
>   Sometimes a screen doesn't have a strict position within the app's hierarchy, and can be reached from multiple entry points—such as a settings screen that can be reached from any other screen in your app. In this case, the Up button should choose to return to the referring screen, behaving identically to Back.

Although `Activity` C can be reached from multiple entry points, its position inside the app hierarchy is very clear, it is the detailed view of an element of the list of `Activity` B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your up button should return you to Activity B - as suggested by the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

> The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the
>   hierarchical relationships between screens. For instance, if screen A
>   displays a list of items, and selecting an item leads to screen B
>   (which presents that item in more detail), then screen B should offer
>   an Up button that returns to screen A.

Comment: Edited - I'll go have some coffee now.

Comment: Sure, however the statement about the "multiple entry points" confuses me.

Comment: They're referring to activities that have no place within the app hierarchy, such as a settings screen. Your `Activity B/C` has a clear place.